# ordering array keys?

Tags: php

i want to create an array with 2 keys and i want them in following order:

```
$array['higher'];
$array['escalate'];
```

how could i accomplish this without creating any value.

i want to add values to the array with later on...

```
$array['higher'][] = 'some_value';
$array['escalate'][] = 'some_value';
```

...but first i need to create the keys in that order.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's no easier way than

```
$array = array("higher" => null, "escalate" => null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define it without adding values

```
$array['A'] = NULL;
$array['B'] = NULL;
```